# Is it illegal to give my friend money for drugs?

Tags: texas, drugs

I live in Texas and my friend wants me to give them Bitcoin in order for them to buy drugs online. I will not ever see these drugs or partake in them, I would simply just give the money to my friend so that they can buy drugs online. Will I get in any trouble for doing this?

Comment: Why can't they get their own bitcoin?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Helping someone to commit a criminal offense is generally a crime identical to the offense itself. Under [Texas Penal Code section 7.02](https://casetext.com/statute/texas-codes/penal-code/title-2-general-principles-of-criminal-responsibility/chapter-7-criminal-responsibility-for-conduct-of-another/subchapter-a-complicity/section-702-criminal-responsibility-for-conduct-of-another):

> A person is criminally responsible for an offense committed by the conduct of another if ... he solicits, encourages, directs, aids, or attempts to aid the other person to commit the offense.

Comment: In addition to being a purchase of an illegal substance, the use of bitcoin in the scenario may very well constitute money laundering, a federal offense.